# Every topological manifold admits a countable, locally finite cover by precompact open sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds

In introduction to smooth manifolds by John M. Lee lemma 2.16 states that:

Every topological manifold admits a countable, locally finite cover by precompact open sets.

And a proof starts like this:

Let ${Ui}$ be any countable cover of M by precompact open sets (for
example, small coordinate balls will do).

How can we take coordinate balls if we don't know whether charts map open subsets of manifold to open balls? We only know charts map open subsets of manifold to open subsets of $R^n$, not necessarily open balls.

I know that topological manifold has countable basis, but are these basis sets precompact?

Can you give me an example of manifold with atlas such that there is a chart or there are many charts that map open subsets of manifold to open subsets of $R^n$ but these open subsets of $R^n$ are not open balls?

Comment: Every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$  contains an open ball.  You can co-restrict your maps to those balls.

Comment: But then my base sets aren't homeomorphic with these open balls, I have to restrict domain of my charts and then It might be the case it is no longer a cover.

Comment: Well, whatever the precise axiomatization may be, very likely one desired early lemma is existence of partitions of unity... So, to my perception, by this year, it's not really about "axioms for smooth manifolds", as about key facts that allow us to do (at least) the usual things on them. But, sure, foundationally, there's possibly something to discuss...

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove that each $x \in M$ has a precompact open neighborhood.

Let $B_r(y)$ denote the open ball in $\mathbb R^n$ having center $y$ and radius $r$.

Take any chart $\phi : U \to U'$ with $x \in U$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r(\phi(x)) \subset U'$. Then $V' = B_{r/2}(\phi(x))$ is open neighborhood of  $\phi(x)$ whose closure $C$ is copact and contained in $U'$. Then $V = \phi^{-1}(V')$ is an open neigborhood of $x \in M$ whose closure is $\phi^{-1}(C)$ which is compact (since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism).

What we have done here is to shrink the codomain $U'$ of a given chart $\phi$ to a small ball whose closure is compact and contained in $U'$.

Let us next prove that $M$ has a countable basis $\mathcal B'$ consisting of precompact open sets. This basis can be taken as the desired cover.

Let $\mathcal B$ be a countable basis for $M$. Define
$$\mathcal B' = \{ B \in \mathcal B \mid \overline B \text{ is compact}\}. $$
This set is clearly countable. Let us show that it is basis which means that for each $x \in M$ and each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$
there exists $B \in \mathcal B'$ such that $x \in B \subset U$.

Take any precompact open neighborhood $U^*$ of $x$. There exists $B \in \mathcal B$ such that $x \in B \subset U \cap U^*$. Then $\overline B$ is a closed subset of $M$ which is contained in the closure of $U^*$ which is compact. Hence $\overline B$ is compact.

Comment: But why it helps? Still it is not necessarily countable cover

Comment: @romperextremeabuser See my update.

Comment: thank you, I got it now